# Error en mi codigo C

Tags: c

Hola estoy comenzando con programación I en esta oportunidad me piden que realice una estructura simple y una doble en C, con la simple excelente, pero en el momento de realizar la estructura doble donde me piden que al ingresar un numero identifique si es par positivo y si no que indique que no es par positivo me da error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que le falta a mi codigo para que me indique cuando no sea par positivo?. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Lo primero, cuando hagas una pregunta intenta poner tu código en formato de texto (hay una opción en la edición de la pregunta para ponerlo en el formato de código), en vez de emplear fotos. De esta manera podemos copiar el código y compilarlo en nuestras máquinas. De todos modos, el fallo que tienes tú es que en la instrucción `if` tienes un `;` al final. Quítalo y te funcionará. Se te queda de la siguiente manera... `if ((numero%2 == 0) && (numero >= 0))` <- Sin el `;` al final

Comment: Soy daltónico y no puedo leer bien el código de la imagen; además el código en imagen no se puede copiapegar, ni se puede compilar ni se pueden buscar palabras sobre el... así que el código en imagen no sirve para nada. Además, esta es una página de programación, no de capturas de pantalla: publica tu código, no una foto del mismo.

Comment: Hola, bienvenida a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) que no esté en una captura de pantalla. Las capturas de pantalla no nos ayudan a reproducir tu problema. Usa la función de copiar/pegar y luego aplica el botón de formato de código.

Comment: La solución te la ha dado [@Londo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/231277/londo). Te aconsejo que uses siempre bloques delimitados por llaves `{...}` aunque únicamente haya una instrucción dentro de ellas. También te recomiendo sangrar adecuadamente el código que escribas. Ambas sugerencias te evitarán dolores de cabeza, harán el código legible y facilitará su análisis y depuración.

Comment: Intenta no poner imágenes donde debería ir código, consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema tiene una solución muy sencilla, y te recomiendo que uses siempre esta mejora, porque como posible futuro programador, esto podrá ayudar a tus compañeros a poder revisar tu código en el futuro.

Usa siempre `{}` para if/else, aunque sólo exista una opción o una línea de ejecución. En tu caso, la solución es:

```
if((numero % 2 == 0) && (numero >= 0)) {
    printf("El número es par positivo");
} else {
    printf("El número no es par positivo");
}
```

Ya que, según tu código, al haber puesto `;` al final del if, el compilador ejecuta tu `if` como una sentencia simple (tipo sumar, ejecutar un método, guardar un valor) y luego, hace el print.

Pero, como además tienes un else debajo, es compilador buscará un `if` que lo contenga, ya que, a diferencia del `if`, sí es posible tener mil `if`s individuales, pero no puedes tener un `else` sin estar contenido en su `if`.